# Telegram Bot API media_group_id usage in send_media_group method

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm trying to store media_group_id value in a database for later reference to the photos.
But I'm unable to send it as a MediaGroup using
using types.send_media_group method.
What's the mechanism of sending a media group of photos? I tried:

```
file=types.InputMediaPhoto('12338991854684052')
bot.send_media_group(message.from_user.id,[file,])
```

P.S: I'm using pyTelegramBotAPI library

Answer (score 0):

Well, Because mediaGroupId is not equaled to mediaPhotoVideos.

You would like to record down multi messages with photos from the same media group ID and resend it with sendMediaGroup.

Just a note. You need to restrict photos from 2 to 9 for each message.